# Reading raw bytes from standard input in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to read in bytes from standard input in Rust. The code below works perfectly for lines consisting of regular characters, but for raw bytes that don't have associated characters (such as `0xe0`), this causes the program to panic. The [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line) says that it will terminate at the newline character, but doesn't mention any issues with non-character bytes.

EDIT: I actually missed that it does say that all bytes must be UTF-8 encoded- is there another function I can use to do this?

```
    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)
        .ok()
        .expect("Couldn't read line");
```

Comment: From the link to the docs that you gave: "This function has the same error semantics as `read_until` and will also return an error if the read bytes are not valid UTF-8."

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thank you, I missed that. Are there any alternative to read the bytes otherwise?

Comment: @UnsolvedCypher: Do you have non-text data that is delimited by newline characters? That seems strange, but if that's really the case, then your alternative is the function mentioned in Warren's comment. `read_until`.

Comment: Not too strange. Isn't that how http works for example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that [Stdin](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html) implements the [Read](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html) trait, so I was able to use the [bytes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.bytes) method:

```
for i in io::stdin().bytes() {
    println!("read byte {}", i.unwrap());
}
```

And this loop can be broken out of by checking each byte until it's the desired byte.

Comment: I don't really see any advantage of this approach over using `read_until()` as suggested in the comments. For stdin, the approach in this answer may be OK, since stdin is always buffered in Rust. Don't try this with an unbuffered file, though – it will result in a system call for every single byte you read, so you will get abysmal performance.

Comment: @SvenMarnach this may just be my inexperience in Rust, but I couldn't figure out how to call read_until() on stdin, all of the examples I found were for reading from files or other buffers.

Comment: You need to `lock()` stdin first. The resulting `StdinLock` object implements `BufRead`, and `read_until()` is a method of that trait.

Comment: See also the [second example on the documentation of `stdin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/fn.stdin.html).